# CSV file saved as another CSV file changing format of date from dd/mm to mm/dd

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA - am saving a csv file as another csv file. Somehow it's changing the date format from dd/mm to mm/dd

So date which was 2/8 (2nd Aug) is changed to 8/2 (8 feb). Any suggestions?

Code am using:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim shttocopy As Worksheet
Dim wbname As String
Dim getdt As String
wbname = Year(Date) & Right("0" & Month(Date), 2) & Right("0" & Day(Date), 2)
wbname = "OOS_" & wbname & ".csv"

Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("..\" & wbname)

wkbSource.SaveAs Filename:="..\OOS_today.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV


wkbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Help please!

Comment: Are you just renaming a CSV file? As soon as you open a CSV in Excel it will fiddle with dates, padding etc. Don't open a CSV in Excel to rename it - just rename it directly without even opening it!

Comment: Excel will read it using the System Locale, it's a nasty problem if you are working with clients/vendors in different date formats (i.e., USA versus *the rest of the world*, etc.) unfortunately. To rename files, simply do the statement: `Name "..\" & wbname As "..\OOS_today.csv"` (you may need full file path in the `Name` command).